# Postman post for creating a user via API results in a CSRF error - Why is that?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am currently experimenting with Postman.

I currently have a view that basically creates a user via a REST call as such
I am using django rest for that

```
class CreateEmployer_CreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = Serializer_CreateEmployer_RX
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    user = request.user
    serializer = Serializer_CreateEmployer_RX(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        Savedmodel = serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is in urls.py

```
url(r"^create/$", csrf_exempt(CreateEmployer_CreateAPIView.as_view()),name="Create"),
```

When I attempt to call this api via Postman I get the error

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
```

My question is why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it ? From what I have read abut CSRF is that when a form is loaded in a webpage a cookie with a CSRF value is sent along with the form and then on submitting the form the values of the CSRF token are compared to make sure it was sent by the same form that was rendered by the view.Now in my case there is no form and the authentication on this view is `AllowAny`. Also this used to work before but now all of a sudden I am getting this error. My question is how can I fix this ? How do I get a CSRF token value in this case since there are no forms ? I have looked at a lot of posts regarding this issue and postman however most of them which I understood suggested adding a `X-CSRFToken` in the header. Even if I add those how do i get the values?

[image]

Comment: Can you add POSTMAN screenshot?

Comment: yes ill update my answer

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge updated my answer

Comment: Did you use **Interceptor** in POSTMAN ?

Comment: Try to remove `csrf_exempt` from urls

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge first I did not have that `csrf_exempt`. After switching my db from sqlite to Postgres I started having this issue.

Comment: Can you show the **Full Window screenshot** of POSTMAN? Is there any way to re-produce the behaviour?If your project is **not classified**, share it, I'll give a try